# Compiled JS from TypeScript does not run in browser

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, three.js

TypeScript code compiles correctly. But (probably) due to my class structure ends up compiling different than expected. Resulting in runtime errors.

The actual issue that is causing the error itself is

```
this.Scene = new THREE.Scene();
```

after running tsc I get this line

```
this.Scene = new three_1.default.Scene();
```

I can just remove the default parameter and that fixes it. But it seems like a bad idea to do that every time. I'd rather know the underlying issue.
Classes for context in case its related to the structure I'm using.
Sorry in advance, I am relatively new to typescript (and started JS a week ago, but I do have a degree in .NET)

```
import { MaterialLibrary } from "./Materials/MaterialLibrary";
import { MeshLoader } from "./MeshLoader";
import THREE from "three";

export class Manager
{
    //manager instance
    private static instance: Manager;

    //sub-managers
    public static MaterialLib: MaterialLibrary;
    public static Scene: THREE.Scene;

    //helper classes
    public static MeshLoader: MeshLoader;

    constructor()
    {
        Manager.instance = this;
    }

    static Init()
    {
        this.MaterialLib = new MaterialLibrary();
        this.MeshLoader = new MeshLoader();
        this.Scene = new THREE.Scene();
    }

    static GetInstance(): Manager
    {
        if(!Manager.instance)
        {
            Manager.instance = new Manager();
        }

        return Manager.instance;
    }
}
```

And this compiles to

```
"use strict";
var __importDefault = (this && this.__importDefault) || function (mod) {
    return (mod && mod.__esModule) ? mod : { "default": mod };
};
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const MaterialLibrary_1 = require("./Materials/MaterialLibrary");
const MeshLoader_1 = require("./MeshLoader");
const three_1 = __importDefault(require("three"));
class Manager {
    constructor() {
        Manager.instance = this;
    }
    static Init() {
        this.MaterialLib = new MaterialLibrary_1.MaterialLibrary();
        this.MeshLoader = new MeshLoader_1.MeshLoader();
        this.Scene = new three_1.default.Scene();
    }
    static GetInstance() {
        if (!Manager.instance) {
            Manager.instance = new Manager();
        }
        return Manager.instance;
    }
}
exports.Manager = Manager;
```

Comment: why do you use a different syntax importing THREE and Meshloader? Does THREE define __esModule?

Comment: Well, the simple answer is that I trusted VS Code to correctly interpret the import syntax. I have no idea if THREE defines __esModule. Thats what the Typescript transpiler turned that into... It is worth noting though that my first 2 imports are custom classes I wrote while three is not in my project directly.

Comment: are you using rollup or webpack?

Comment: Im using browsify right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
```

instead of

```
import THREE from 'three';
```

see: https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/Import-via-modules

Comment: Seems like my typescript compiler still does the same thing with this... Weird, I assume this should be interpreted differently?

Comment: yes, they are really different in what they do. The first one will import everything exported from the module 'three' and assign it to the variable THREE, the second will only import what was exported with `export default` in the THREE-module. I don't know enough about your setup to help any further though.

Comment: I've tried to simplify my code a bit and redid most of it in a single file at first to see if it works, with an error on the __esmodule.

https://pastebin.com/WKqb8XiK compiles to https://pastebin.com/07vfngAy causing Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
    at main.js:2. Not sure if this is related or if i should make a new post for that

Comment: I think it would be much more interesting to see your build-setup. Most od these problems are hiding somewhere between tsc, babel, browserify and whatever you use. The source-code itself looks fine.